# TypeError: both int and float

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self,holder, number, balance, credit_line = 1500):
        self.holder = holder
        self.number = number
        self.balance = balance
        self.credit_line = credit_line

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if(self.balance - amount < -self.credit_line):
           return False
        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return True

    def balance(self):
        return self.balance
    def holder(self):
        return self.holder

    def transfer(self, target, amount):
        if(self.balance - amount < -self.credit_line):
           #coverage insufficient
           return False
        else:
             self.balance -= amount
             target.balance += amount
             return True 
Guido = Account("Guido", 10 ,1000.50)
Guido.balance()
-------------------------------------------------------------------------


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Account.py", line 31, in <module>
    Guido.balance()
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Comment: `self.balance = amount` overwrites the `balance` function

Comment: The other answers have explained the issue, but I just want to say that "accessors" like your `balance` and `holder` methods are generally not needed in Python. You can just have your outside code access the attribute (which in this case was the same name, leading to the issue) directly. If you later find you need to do some special processing to the value (e.g. round it off to a certain number of decimal places), you can use a `property` to turn the attribute lookup into a function call.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding method `balance` in your `__init__` method. You could either change the field name to `_balance` or just remove `balance` method and use `Guido.balance`.

Also note, that you should name your variables starting with lowercase character (i.e. `guido = Account(...)`, not `Guido`)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self,holder, number, balance, credit_line = 1500):
        self.holder = holder
        self.number = number
        self.balance = balance
        self.credit_line = credit_line

    def deposit(self, amount):
        self.balance = amount
    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
           print "Amount greater than available balance"

        else:
            self.balance -= amount
            return True

    def bala_nce(self):
        return self.balance
    def hold_er(self):
        return self.holder
    def num(self):

        return self.number


    def transfer(self, target, amount):
        if(self.balance - amount < -self.credit_line):
           #coverage insufficient
           return False
        else:
             self.balance -= amount
             target.balance += amount
             return True 

guido = Account("Guido", 10 ,10000.100)
guido.withdraw(2300.100)

print "Account name: " ,guido.hold_er()
print  "available balance: $",guido.bala_nce()
```

thanx to you soon............... its working now